# opencv linking error after mixing c++ with c version

Tags: opencv, eclipse-cdt, windows-7-x64

I'm working with opencv 2.4.0 using eclipse CDT (Indigo Service Release 2) on windows 7 64 bit machine. I complied opencv from sources (using cmake/visual studio express 10) following the steps described on the opencv download site.

Everything worked well when I was using opencv C functions (in my C++ code). When I tried to use cv::Mat, it gave me a linking error (like: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(_IplImage const*, bool)').

- What libraries do I need to link with to make opencv C++ functions work along with pure C ones? I've already linked with opencv_core240 and others that I needed and it worked fine for opencv C functions.
- I noticed 2 versions of ocv libraries, one with a suffix 'd', so opencv_core240 and opencv_core240d. What is the difference between the 2?

Comment: Suffix 'd' - debug version, without suffix - release.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IplImage *image = cvLoadImage("C:\\any_picture.jpg");
    Mat m = Mat(image);
    imshow("test",m);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

1. try the above code by linking the debug files like opencv_core240d.lib,opencv_highgui240d.lib,opencv_imgproc240d.lib
2. add the path to the bin folder to the environment variable
3. try to get the latest opencv i.e. 2.4.3

Comment: Still the same problem! The code compiles, but linking errors to all the functions except cvLoadImage().
I'll get opencv 2.4.3 and try with that.

Comment: same error with 2.4.3 as well! on the other hand it works just fine when compiled in Visual Studio Express 10 (instead of using Eclipse/MinGW GCC toolchain). next tried to compile opencv itself with eclipse but the compilation ended with just a bunch of .a files in opencv lib/ directory (so no .lib files were generated). In CMake I used 'Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles' option as the generator. Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: Make sure the compiler you choose to build the libs n bins of opencv with CMAKE (try using the GUI version of CMAKE..) the same compiler should be preferably used to run the program...I am mostly into Qt and VS so pardon me for the fact that I cant guide you much about eclipse...however the steps which you followed are generic and should work..

Answer (score 0):

found a solution. when using eclipse with mingw tool chain you should compile opencv with mingw as well. compiling opencv from command line worked for me.

1. follow section 'Compile using GCC from command line' from the opencv [InstallGuide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide)
2. in addition to mingw32-make, make -j, also do a 'make install'. this will create an install directory in the folder where you build your opencv binaries. the opencv libraries will be placed be install/lib
3. the lib files in install/lib will have a '.dll.a' extension like 'libopencv_core243.dll.a'. 
   to link to these lib files in your project go to Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Libraries. then add the library name without the prefix 'lib' and suffix '.dll.a'. so to link to 'libopencv_core243.dll.a' just use 'opencv_core243'